# python - cast a class to a tuple and "autobox" to a for loop

Tags: python, tuples

I was wondering, is there a way in which I can cast a class instance to a tuple in the following way:
Say we have a class A with fields x and y, and we have a list l which contains A instances. I would like to do the following if it's possible:

```
for (x, y) in l:
     print x + y #just an example
```

I was thinking to use `__iter__` to return x and y but it didn't quite work. casting to tuple was working fine but it couldn't autobox the objects in l to (x,y) in the for loop

I know it sounds little silly but a friend was challenging me for something he was working on and I just couldn't do it even though it seems doable

Comment: This isn't really "casting"; thinking of it in C++-esque terms will probably mislead you (and make it hard for you to search for answers).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you *can* do it with `__iter__`:

```
def __iter__(self):
    yield self.x
    yield self.y
```

but I wouldn't recommend it.

If you're sure you want this thing to be treatable as a tuple, you could use a `namedtuple` class:

```
import collections
XAndYClass = collections.namedtuple('XAndYClass', 'x y')
xandy = XAndYClass(1, 2)
print xandy.x # prints 1
x, y = xandy # x = 1, y = 2
```

You can inherit from that to add methods, if you want.

```
class XAndYWithMethods(XAndYClass):
    def method(self):
        print 'doing stuff...'
```

Comment: On top of the benefits of `namedtuple` cited here, you also get you `xandy[0] == xandy.x`, and a free constructor, and in general make it clear that your attributes have an ordering that's as important as their names.

Comment: yea was thinking about namedtuple but hoped i'd learn something new... anyway thanks :)